# Prediction Confidence Intervals when fitting a GAM model using gam package

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-additive-model, prediction-interval, mgcv

Is there any way to get a prediction confidence interval from a model fit with **gam** package? Working with *mgcv* is not an option for me as it doesn't provide as good fit as gam does on my data.

The documentation on **predict.gam** says:

*Currently predict.Gam does not produce standard errors for predictions at newdata.*

It also states that:

*When newdata are supplied, predict.Gam simply invokes inheritance and gets predict.glm to produce the parametric part of the predictions.*

**Would it be correct to generate it by using the function *predict.glm()* even though my model have only smoother terms?**

If it wouldn't be, is there any set of parameters that the fit model returns from where I could build the confidence interval I am looking for?

Any workaround/idea will be very welcome!

Comment: I find it exceedingly hard to believe that `gam::gam()` provides a fit that `mgcv::gam()` cannot, *unless* the former has achieved an unreasonable fit. Perhaps if you post a Q about the difference we can solve that issue?